# Transpose a result with an unknown number of rows/columns

Tags: postgresql, pivot, transpose

Let's say I have a query that yields these results:

```
           2015-2016  |  2016-2017  |  2017-2018
-----------------------------------------------
Alpha          2             5            9
Bravo          7             14           21
Charlie        1             2            4
```

But I want the results to be transposed like this:

```
           Alpha  |  Bravo  |  Charlie
-----------------------------------------------
2015-2016    2         7          1
2016-2017    5         14         2
2017-2018    9         21         4
```

**AND...** my original results will have an *arbitrary* number of rows (to be turned to columns), which I cannot know in advance. For example, `Echo` and `Foxtrot` might appear some day but I won't know their names in advance.

Is there a way to simply transpose / pivot this table, without knowing the contents or length of the table in advance?

I've seen similar questions, where the answer ended up being to use `unpivot` or `crosstab`, but they all seem to require a knowledge of the output structure in advance.

Comment: Not possible. The database needs to know the number of columns **before** actually running the query. This is a limitation of the SQL language. It's not specific to Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, it seems like you're right, so go ahead and submit your comment as an answer, which I'll accept.